# Error: "The model is structurally singular" Dymola Modelica Solar thermal coupled with hot water tank and floor heating

Tags: modelica, dymola, building, solar

Here what I am doing is that using the weather data as input parameter, if the global radiation is higher than 100 W/m^2 open the valve. First solar heat will be released to the hot water tank, and then the heat will be given to the Boundry_pT via heat exchanger. I want to see, how the temperature of *Boundry_pt* changes resp. time.
I also want to use water as *Medium* in the internal heat exchanger. For that I edited the text box in Medium in the heat exchanger, as *Buildings_Media_Water*. Is it correct? Otherweise how can I choose water as a medium in the internal heat exchanger?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Very hard to say from the picture. Please provide code...

Comment: And open up the "The problem is structurally singular..."; as the real error message is hidden there.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have two separate fluid-circuits, and you only have one expansion tank (the "exp" component - sorry if I don't have the right terminology).

That means that the flow becomes over-determined in the 2nd circuit - and the pressure under-determined. There are a number of ways of handling it - including adding an expansion tank.